# IPA von Haeckel (Hegel, Händel, ...)

Tags: pronunciation, person-names

Ich bin mir unsicher, ob und wie ich die IPA-Wiedergabe von **Haeckel** im [englischen Wikipediartikel über Ernst Haeckel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Haeckel) korrigieren oder ergänzen soll.

Dort steht [ˈhɛkəl], mir scheint aber auch [ˈhɛkl̩] richtig zu sein.

Das IPA, was benutzt werden kann, steht [hier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_German).

Ich sehe vier Möglichkeiten:

1. [ˈhɛkəl] or [ˈhɛkl̩]
2. [ˈhɛk(ə)l]
3. [ˈhɛkl̩]
4. es bei [ˈhɛkəl] zu lassen.

Ein kleineres, höher gestelltes ə (<sup>ə</sup>, Unicode: ᵊ = U+1D4A modifier letter small schwa) scheint nicht zur Verfügung zu stehen, und auch nicht angebracht zu sein.

Welche ist die beste Lösung?

P.S.: Dasselbe Problem scheinen auch [Hegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Wilhelm_Friedrich_Hegel), [Händel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Frideric_Handel) u. a. zu haben

Comment: Ich bin mir unsicher, ob das hier das richtige Forum für diese Frage ist. Wie Sprecher des Englischen deutsche Namen aussprechen, zumal häufig kein nennenswertes Bemühen erkennbar ist, die originale Aussprache beizubehalten (vgl. die Frage zur Aussprache von "Euler"), würde ich eher im Englisch-Forum platzieren.

Comment: @guidot na dem Trend muss man ja nicht helfen indem man die Fehler der Originalaussprache stehenlässt. Wider des Broken-Window-Effects!1!

Comment: @guidot in Wikipedia wird durch das [IPA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationales_Phonetisches_Alphabet) die _richtige_ deutsche Aussprache angegeben – außer vielleicht für Einzelheiten wie diese, worum es geht.

Comment: @WalterTross „Richtig“ ist gerade in Bezug auf die Aussprache (oder auch Schreibung) von Namen ein problematisches Konzept – bspw. wird mein Familienname dank _ä_ und _er_ trotz nur zwei Silben in fünf Buchstaben allein von seinen mir bekannten Trägern auf mindestens vier phonetisch unterschiedliche Arten ausgesprochen und davon ist keine richtiger als die andere, aber einige, die man von Fremden zu hören bekommt, klingen *auf mich* definitiv falsch.

Answer (score 4):

**Phonetisch¹** ist der Unterschied zwischen [ˈhɛkl̩] und [ˈhɛkəl] minimal und es gibt einen fließenden Übergang, da [k] als [Plosiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plosiv) natürlicherweise ein Ausatmen, also zumindest ein leichtes Schwa nach sich zieht. Der Unterschied zwischen [ˈhɛkl̩] und [ˈhɛkəl] liegt also darin, ob nur ein minimales Schwa oder mehr vorliegt. Die reale Aussprache ist nah am minimalen Schwa und wird dadurch wohl durch [ˈhɛkl̩] am besten wiedergegeben.

**Phonemisch¹** werden ähnliche deutsche Wörter werden gewöhnlicherweise mit Schwa dargestellt, z. B. wird *Deckel* als /dɛkəl/ dargestellt, da das Deutsche nicht zwischen den Aussprachen [ˈdɛkl̩] und [ˈdɛkəl] unterscheidet – *Deckl* ist kein eigenständiges Wort und wenn Muttersprachler versuchen, das Wort besonders deutlich auszusprechen, ist das Schwa klar vorhanden (es wird also als existent empfunden). Was man nun als Darstellung in diesem Fall wählt, ist aber letztlich eine Frage der Konvention und ich persönlich würde /dɛkl/ nicht als falsch ansehen.

Da sich der entsprechende Aussprachehinweis an Leser richtet, die des Deutschen nicht mächtig sind und also insbesondere nicht mit Konventionen der phonetischen Darstellung des Deutschen vertraut sind, sollte er phonetisch und nicht phonemisch sein. Deswegen würde ich [ˈhɛkl̩] bevorzugen. Andererseits würde ich von Sprechern des Englischen erwarten, dass sie auch bei [ˈhɛkəl] dem Schwa nicht übermäßiges Gewicht verleihen, da das gleiche Phänomen auch bei englischen Wörtern wie *shackle* auftaucht. Ein Vorteil von [ˈhɛkəl] ist wohl, dass niemand versuchen wird, das Schwa übermäßig zu unterdrücken und sich dabei die Zunge verknotet.

---

¹ Zur Unterscheidung von *phonetisch* und *phonemisch* siehe z. B. [hier](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lautlehre).

Comment: Gute Antwort, bin aber mit folgendem Satz nicht einverstanden: “Andererseits würde ich von Sprechern des Englischen erwarten, dass sie auch bei [ˈhɛkəl] dem Schwa nicht übermäßiges Gewicht verleihen”. Das Schwa ist nicht, weil es Schwa heißt, schwächer. Ich habe jedenfalls die "radikale Möglichkeit", also nur [ˈhɛkl̩], zu meiner Frage hinzugefügt. Welche ist letzten Endes deine Wahl, 1, 2, 3 oder 4?

Comment: @WalterTross: *bin aber mit folgendem Satz nicht einverstanden* – Ich habe eine Begründung hinzugefügt. — *Welche ist letzten Endes deine Wahl, 1, 2, 3 oder 4?* – Ich finde 1 unnötig verwirrend an der Stelle. Ansonsten sehe ich die Varianten als gleichwertig an und würde der Konsistenz mit dem Rest der Wikipedia Vorrang geben.

Comment: Also `[ˈhɛkl̩]` oder `/ˈhɛkəl/`? Nur `hekl` (ohne Schwa und Diakritikum) geht weder phonetisch noch phonemisch, weil es eindeutig einsilbig wäre. `hekᵊl` wäre wahrscheinlich – sofern es jeweils korrekt dargestellt wird – für viele verständlicher als `ˈhɛkl̩` und der Unterschied ist marginal.

Comment: @Crissov: Das Diakritikum in der Frage ist dem Monospace-Satz zum Opfer gefallen (zumindest bei mir). Für ein hochgestelltes Schwa müsste man, wie in der Frage geschrieben, die [Aussprache-Hilfe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_German) anpassen; [l̩] ist dort bereits enthalten.

Comment: Wenn man “shackle pronunciation” sucht kommen auch /ˈʃæk(ə)l/ und /ˈʃækᵊl/ vor… Danke für das Edit, das Problem vom diakritischen Zeichen ist sowohl Betriebssystem- als auch Browser-abhängig. In Firefox auf Ubuntu ist durch das Edit das Zeichen von der eckigen Klammer fast bis unter das k geraten. Mit Safari auf Mac ist es aber so besser, obwohl für Firefox kein Problem bestand.

Comment: *Wenn man “shackle pronunciation” sucht kommen auch /ˈʃæk(ə)l/ und /ˈʃækᵊl/ vor…* – Eben, es ist die gleiche Situation.

Comment: Nach näherem Durchlesen finde ich deine Antwort leider nicht überzeugend. Phonemisch ist alles schön und gut, aber die IPA-Widergabe von Deutsch in der englischen Wikipedia ist richtigerweise immer phonetisch, also in eckigen Klammern ("as opposed to slashes"). Dass der  Unterschied zwischen [ˈhɛkl̩] und [ˈhɛkəl] minimal ist finde ich auch nicht so richtig. Das empfinden vielleicht Deutsch- und Englischsprecher, aber die englische Wikipedia wird ja nicht nicht nur von diesen gelesen. Letztlich is Wikipedia immer verbesserbar. Das [l̩] ist auf der Help-Seite erst am 24.6.2015 eingeführt worden.